# Масштабирование игровых объектов Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Всем привет.
Хочу портировать некоторые свои игровые наработки на телефон. С первой минуты столкнулся со следующими особенностями.
Внутри редактора Unity3D я настроил отображение камеры на соотношение сторон 16:9. И внутри редактора объекты выглядят нормально. Так, как я бы хотел видеть их в телефоне.
Я был удивлён, когда после запуска приложения на телефоне, все объекты разъехались кто куда.

Так, выглядит образец на компьютере. Выноска для отображения текста по середине, текст внутри неё
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это после запуска на телефоне.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Говоря проще, я не совсем понимаю, как настраивать игровые объекты, что-бы на устройствах с разной диагональю, объекты выравнивались относительно экрана. Причём не только те, что нарисовал и добавил я сам, но и элементы типа Текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это связано с конкретными настройками в `RectTransform` ваших объектов, которые находятся внутри `Canvas`-а. А конкретно с полями `anchor` и `pivot` этих элементов.

От них зависит к какой точке (в координатах или в процентах от экрана)привязаны объекты и то, как они реагируют на изменение размера экрана.

Подробнее можете почитать [в документации Unity по ссылке](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html). Там с примерами показано, как реагируют элементы на те или иные настройки этих полей.

Comment: Попутно созрел ещё вопрос:
Поле отображения Canvas и то, что видит камера, находится в разных частях экрана. Как можно исправить это?
Если вы поднимитесь на первый скрин, то можно заметить две белые границы.

Comment: @Любитель, это зависит от режима установленного в поле RednerMode Canvas-а. Чтобы холст "натягивался" на камеру нужен режим Screen Space - Camera и ссылка на камеру в поле RenderCamera. Подробнее тоже в документации по Canvas https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html